# How to send an image and additional data body using fetch

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to upload an image to a serverless function on firebase.
I'm sending the request like this:

```
const updateProfileImage = (image) => {
        fetch(
            "http://localhost:5001/yelpcamp-d57d1/us-central1/uploadImage",
            {
                // Your POST endpoint
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    // Content-Type may need to be completely **omitted**
                    // or you may need something
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    image: image,
                    userID: userID,
                }),
            }
        )
            .then(
                (response) => response.json() // if the response is a JSON object
            )
            .then(
                (success) => console.log(success) // Handle the success response object
            )
            .catch(
                (error) => console.log(error) // Handle the error response object
            );
    };
```

But I'm only receiving this on the other end:

```
 {"image":{},"userID":"*ID*"}
```

I'm not sure why the image data was removed, what is the correct way to do this?

The image file is retrieved from a HTML input like so:

```
<input
            name={id}
            id={id}
            type="file"
            style={{
                width: "0.1px",
                height: "0.1px",
                opacity: "0",
                overflow: "hidden",
                position: "absolute",
                zIndex: "-1",
            }}
            onChange={(e) => {
                uploadImage(e.target.files[0]);
            }}
/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add what exactly `image` is as a variable.

Comment: @Rojo How do you mean?

Comment: `image: image,` what is the second `image` supposed to be?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's an image taken directly from a HTML input type file. Do I need add something so it recognises it?

Comment: I don't know exactly what that means. You should edit your post and add how you get the URL with HTML and JS.

Comment: Okay I've edited it to show how the image file is uploaded by the user and passed in to the function, hopefully that makes more sense? I'm trying to send the actual image file as opposed to a URL.